# How to get the position of a pointer for a list

Tags: tcl

I am having a list say test

```
set test "Hi i am Nitesh"
regexp "am" $test
tell test # to ge the position of the pointer
```

I am getting an error as

```
can not find channel named "test"
```

Dont know how to do that

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have 2 totally different concepts here. On one hand you have a list, and you want to find the position of a term in the list. Then, on the other hand, you are using **tell** (normally used to determine access position for an open channel). I suspect that what you really need is to search the string called test. Try using http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M8

```
set test "Hi i am Nitesh"
string first "am" $test
```

If you want to treat test as a list, then simply use [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lsearch.htm) to find the list index.

```
lsearch $test am
```

Comment: I concur. @Nitesh, it seems you did not even bother to peer into the `regexp` and `tell` manual pages.

Comment: @Nitesh, have I answered your question sufficiently, or do you require more help?